# Issue in requiring a custom module

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, electron

Let's give the context: I am currently working on making a little library for **Electron**.

Since the beginning, I was working on a single JS file containing a class.
But I decided to make a different class (and so another JS file) to have a better organization.

So I made it. I made this file, with an export at the end like I read on many websites.

Unfortunatly, when I try to require my second class in my first one, I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './my-module-two'

Irritating.

I searched for about one hour on Google in order to find a solution, I tried many without result.

There my file contents right now. I cut that I judged unuseful.

---

**my-module-one.js**

```
// I also tried to require here.

class MyModuleOne
{
    constructor() {
        this.MyModuleTwo = require('./my-module-two');
    }
}
```

---

**my-module-two.js**

```
class MyModuleTwo
{
    // Literally nothing. But I tried with a constructor for the same issue.
}

module.exports.MyModuleTwo = MyModuleTwo;
```

---

**index.html**

```html
<!-- Into <head> tags. -->
<script src="js/my-module/my-module-one.js"></script>
```

---

My files are in the same directory:

```
myApp/
   web/
      js/
         my-module/
            my-module-one.js
            my-module-two.js
   node_modules/
      (other directories)/
main.js
package.json
package-lock.json
```

---

Of course, all libraries installed with npm required on **index.html** or **my-module-one.js** works as hell.

Thanks to the one who will be my savior! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should try use `require('./js/my-module/my-module-one')` instead of `<script src="js/my-module/my-module-one.js"></script>`

Comment: You saved me 'cause it is working! I'll mark your answer as the solution, think to edit it to include your comment into it.